# Fetch Firebase/Geofire data only after getting user location

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, geofire

I'm developing a app that uses GeoFire to only get data from Firebase that are in 10km radius from the user location. And then populate a CollectionView.

**The problem:**
When internet is slow it loads the CollectionView with no data. Probably because the mobile didn't have time to get an accurate user location yet.

I have my fetchData() function inside ViewDidLoad().

How can I do to execute fetchData() function only after user location has been finished?

Desired flow:
 - Launch App
 - Get user location
 - Populate the CollectionView with data only after getting user location
 - Load CollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your fetch data function outside ViewDidLoad

```
func fetchData(){
   etc.
}
```

call it when location comes through in:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   guard let location = manager.location else {return}
   etc.
   fetchData()
}
```